# How to run multiple optimizations through IBM CPLEX?

Tags: optimization, model, cplex

I am a student having a large linear energy system model in CPLEX and try to run it multiple times through a for-loop while alternating single input variables. (Sensitivity Analysis)

The server is able to run around 10 optimization without a problem but after that there is a memory error. I tried to delete everything that could cause the memory error through closing the opl-model and closing the result-files, but I don't find that command that really resets everything. Right now I need to manually restart the optimization every 9 hours. That is working with the 100 optimizations I do right now, but in the future I need around 400 optimizations.

The commands I tried are
opl.end -> ending the problem that was generated through `opl.generate`, and
ergs.close -> ergs is the CSV file where all results are written

I also played around with:

`MyCplex.workmem` and `MyCplex.tilim`
both did not have a large influence

the settings right now:

```
    MyCplex.epgap=0.005;
    MyCplex.parallelmode=-1;
    MyCplex.workmem=120000;
    MyCplex.threads=0; 
    thisOplModel.settings.mainEndEnabled=true;
    MyCplex.rootalg=4;  //0=auto,1=primal, 2=dual, 4=barrier
    MyCplex.barepcomp=1e-12;
    MyCplex.solutiontype=2;
```

My questions are therefore:

- How can I document well what happens and so what goes wrong?
- How can I clear the memory thoroughly between optimizations?
- Alternatively, how can I run multiple optimizations one after the other in an automated way (over 100)?

Comment: Hi, do you run with oplrun (command line) or the IDE ?

Comment: Hi :) I use the IDE

Answer (score 0):

You should either move to oplrun to save memory or turn end setting to on:

mainEndEnabled is the setting to turn on in scripting

Example on how to use end after solve at https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/howtowithoplchange/blob/master/changevalue.mod

```
main {
      var source = new IloOplModelSource("subvalue.mod");
      var cplex = new IloCplex();
      var def = new IloOplModelDefinition(source);
     
     
     
      for(var k=1;k<=10;k++)
      {
      var opl = new IloOplModel(def,cplex);
        
      var data2= new IloOplDataElements();
      data2.maxOfx=k;
      opl.addDataSource(data2);
      opl.generate();

      if (cplex.solve()) {  
         opl.postProcess();
         writeln("OBJ = " + cplex.getObjValue());
      } else {
         writeln("No solution");
      }
     opl.end();
    }  
     
    }
```